# How to add groups to my JSON file from adjacency matrix

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, adjacency-matrix

I want to make groups in my JSON file, the groups need to be based on similar links and values as mention below, the code to make the JSON file from a CSV is as follows:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('GephiMatrix_co-authorship.csv', (error, content) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.error('Error while reading file: ', error);
    }

    let lines = content.toString().split('\n');

    // delete the last line
    lines = lines.slice(0, lines.length - 1);

    let nodes = lines.shift().split(';');
    // remove the first node because it is empty
    nodes.shift();

    nodes = nodes.map((node, idx) => ({name: node, id: idx}));

    lines = lines.map(line => {
        let tmp = line.split(';');
        tmp = tmp.slice(1, tmp.length - 1);
        return tmp.map(x => parseFloat(x));
    });

    links = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < lines[0].length; j++) {
            if (lines[i][j] !== 0) {
                links.push({source: i, target: j, weight: lines[i][j]});
            }
        }
    }


    const obj = {
        nodes: nodes,
        links: links 
    }

    fs.writeFile('output3.json', JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4), (errWrite) => {
        if (errWrite) {
            return console.error('There was an error when writing the json output: ', errWrite);
        }
    });
});
```

It outputs this:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": "Jim_Thomas",
            "id": 0
        },
        {
            "name": "Eleftherios_Koutsofios",
            "id": 1
        }, 
        ...

    "links": [
        {
            "source": 0,
            "target": 57,
            "weight": 1
        },
        {
            "source": 1,
            "target": 57,
            "weight": 1
        },
        ...
```

This is very simplified, but as you can see source 0 and 1 (Jim and Eleftherios respectively) have the same target and the same weigthed link, so I want to assign them both to the same group.

So nodes becomes like:

```
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": "Jim_Thomas",
            "id": 0
            "group": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Eleftherios_Koutsofios",
            "id": 1
            "group": 1
        }, 
        ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you come from `target: 57` and `weight: 1` to `group: 1`?

Comment: @NinaScholz The JSON file is very large, with 1053 IDs. ID 0 and 1 have the same target with the same weight on the link, thus they get group 1, but it can be group 5 as well, as long it is the same group.

Comment: but where do i see that this is `group: 1`?

Comment: @NinaScholz what do you mean exactly?

Comment: where can i get the information of `group: 1` in your code?